# Value of the difference if functions

Tags: functions

Is there a relatively simple function $f(x)$ such that $f(x)-f(x-1)=x^n$? Note that $n$ is a positive integer. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer : If you want to find those, at least for integers, you can play around https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=g%280%29%3Da%2C+g%28n%2B1%29%3Dn%5E4%2Bg%28n%29. You can find some functions provided you give $f(0)$, what I see from it is that it almost always exists!